# Hibernate Search and Play Framework, how to build the Index

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework-2.0, hibernate-search

I'm trying to integrate Hibernate Search into a Play Framework application that is already running. I have a Problem with building the Index, or thats what I think is the Problem.

I have a User:

```
@Indexed
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
    @Field
    public String firstname;
    @Field
    public String lastname;
    @Field
    public String email;
}
```

This is my persistence.xml:

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

```
<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>models.User</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"          value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider"
                  value="filesystem"/>

        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase"
                  value="/Users/<user>/lucene/indexes"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

So it seams logical to me that the building of the Index (for the data already in the Database) should happen in the `onStart` of the GlobalAdmin Object. I use a `JPA.withTransaction` to call the Indexer:

```
JPA.withTransaction(new F.Callback0() {
    @Override
    public void invoke() throws Throwable {
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(JPA.em());
        try {
            fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

The Problem is I get:

```
[error] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - Timed out waiting for a free available connection.
[error] o.h.s.e.i.LogErrorHandler - HSEARCH000058: HSEARCH000211: An exception occurred while the MassIndexer was fetching the primary identifiers list
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Timed out waiting for a free available connection.
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.DefaultConnectionStrategy.getConnectionInternal(DefaultConnectionStrategy.java:88) ~[bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.AbstractConnectionStrategy.getConnection(AbstractConnectionStrategy.java:90) ~[bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.getConnection(BoneCP.java:553) ~[bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:131) ~[bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
```

Thanks for your Help.

Edit:

My Search method in controller:

As in the comments suggested, I uncommented the Indexer in the 'onStart'.

```
   @Transactional
    public static Result list(int page, String filter, String sortby, String order) {

        EntityManager em = JPA.em();

        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);

        QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(User.class).get();
        Query luceneQuery = qb
                        .keyword()
                        .onFields("firstname", "lastname", "email")
                        .matching(filter)
                        .createQuery();
        // wrap Lucene query in a javax.persistence.Query
        javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, User.class);
        // execute search
        List result = jpaQuery.getResultList();

        Page<User> userPage = new Page<>(result,1,1,1);

        //Page<User> userPage = User.page(page, 30, sortby, order, filter);
        return ok(views.html.admin.customers.list.render(userPage, filter, sortby, order));
    }
```

This is the method my first attempt to use Hibernate Search. However this does not return anything.

Comment: When you are using the HibernateSearchEntityManager, hibernate will automaticly create and manage index for you;) If you had anotated your entities correctly for indexing. Have a look here: http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/

Comment: Whats wrong with my Annotations?

Are you saying I don't need 'fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();' at all?

Comment: Not in JPA environment. There it is enough to use the correct EntityManager Factory in your persistence unit. I'm not familar with Play, sorry. Your annotations look simple but ok.

Comment: Why then does my code not work?

Comment: I don't know what is the problem, use [Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) if you want to know what do you have in your index.

Comment: Yes use luke to inspect your index and how and what is created. Probaly your filter string in your query is returning nothing.

Comment: When I start the server it generates some files lucene/indexes/models.User/segments.gen  and lucene/indexes/models.User but Luke does not open them. If I select the "models.User" (or any other) it says it "No valid directory at the location, try another location".

Answer (score 1):

Your problem does not seem to lie with Search directly. Looking at the stacktrace, it seems you are running out of JDBC connections. I don't know BoneCP myself, but it seems to be a JDBC pool library. What is your configuration for it? Have you tried to increase the connection pool size?